# Flutter - how to get refreshed Firebase's app token

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Firebase Cloud Messaging. While I was developing and using single AVD to test, I noticed that the token changed.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678248/in-what-period-does-the-firebases-app-token-changes-and-how-to-manage-it), but it does not help when developing with Flutter.

How can I get the new token? Will the *token* change while the app is running or in between app stop and start?

In the other question's answer, it says:

> As you pointed out the token can change, in which case the
>   onTokenRefresh() method will be called again.

How will it happen in case of Flutter?

Comment: it seems more complex with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157236/firebase-cloud-messaging-auth-tokens-vs-registration-token

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to it in Flutter. Use,

```
firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) => saveOrSendToken(token));
```

Comment: withe token change when the app is running or when the app stops and the restarts ?

Comment: both time. Check it with your previous saved token.

Comment: because every time when app start then this callback called. see [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1824)

Comment: @MatthewRideout It is not deprecated in flutter. You have mantioned js library link.